# How to get Root page from master page in sub directory

Tags: asp.net

I have masterpage,contactus,default page in Root of my application 
and my login page in Account Directory

Master page associated with Login and default page

In Master page i have link which is redirecting to contactus

when i am on default page Contact us redirection is proper because both master and default are in Root

Now i got problem is that when i am on login page contact us redirection failed because login page is in Account directory and master is in Root

On my Master page I have link

```
<a href="~/contactus.aspx">Contact us</a>
```

It works when master page is associated with root and not with subdirectory

Please suggest the solution

Comment: Is an error or the anchor element in your actual code has runat="server"?

Comment: no it is without runat attribute

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
<a href="<%=HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath %>contactus.aspx">Contact us</a>
```

[Learn more about HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath property on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationvirtualpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Pay attention to the fact that `~/` notation only works as expected on server-side controls.

Comment: I used Control.Resolve and it does the trick but don't know whether it ideal solution

Comment: @RakeshSawant If you're not using server controls, you should do something like I suggested in my answer. BTW, if you found your own solution, you can either answer your own question or mark mine (or other one) as the right one.